# How to design web responsive grid properly from scratch (if possible)

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive-design

At present, I'm currently working on a client's project to build timesheet/billing system and one of my key tasks is to build a good grid-layout that display the data in their correct places.  We haven't decided which server-side programming platform we're going to use that will be used for this system yet (hence it's in plain html).  The client wants to work with us in getting the aesthetic feel and look of the html layout first before any actual implementation can begin, as part of drafted client requirements...

http://cms.tmaarchive.com.au/timesheet-allemployee.html

Anyway I digress.  If you look at the first row of the grid, you will notice there's a green 'Approve' and red 'Reject' buttons.  Next to the reject button, there's a small slither of blue background colour in the background.  We realised this is not correct and we need to fix this grid layout problem.

At the time of my investigation, I realised that this is more a responsive web design problem as I dont have this issue on my monitor screen 1440x900.  It's laid out perfectly.  But if you place the page on a wider(or smaller) resolution, both height and width respectively, then you will notice the blue background color is becoming more and more apparent.  From this, I realised this is the consequence of not designing web responsive grid from the beginning.  Though, in my own defense, it wasn't that important to address as we were not sure how the grid layout would come turn out in the first place after designing the web designer's mockup from scratch.  Once we got the layout and outlined the baseline of the foundation as we move along the project, then we've become more knowledgeable in evaluating how our grid is going to become responsive later on.

But looks like I have to address them earlier than expected.  Thus I'm under pressure to determine what's the best course of action to take in addressing this pending issue before we can show our to the client.  I heard there's two approaches of grid-based responsive web ie DIY and framework-based and I haven't done responsive web design before and I need your recommendation which of the two is going to help me to correct the layout issues of the page (and eventually use that starting foundation for all other grids within the timesheet billing system.)

Here's the code for layout of the problematic row.

```
<div class="table_row 1">
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 110px;">
        Steven Kugel
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 110px;">
            Mrs Smith
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 60px;">
        03.07.2014
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 110px;text-align:center;">
        3.5
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 120px;text-align:center;">
        80%
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 130px;text-align:center;">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 76px;text-align:center;">
        7.5
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 45px;">
        1,575
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 126px;background-color: #fff;display:inline-flex;">
    &nbsp;
    <div style="float:left;margin-right: 5px;">
        <input type="button" value="Approve" name="APPROVE" style="background-color: #6EBA66;width: 58px; height: 0px; margin-right: 4px; padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 18px;font-size:13px;"></div>
            <div style="float:left;">
    <input type="button" value="Reject" name="REJECT" style="background-color: #D70D1E;width: 58px; height: 0px; margin-right: 4px; padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 18px;font-size:13px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to offer as much criticism if you could, so I can learn to improve my responsive web design skills further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bootstrap or metroui, a standard version for responsive , check the grid system here

```
   http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
```

Comment: Yes. I'm aware about bootstrap.  But do you think its CSS layout positioning properties are too great for this simple grid layout design to work? I'm kinda hesistant to use because of its large range of CSS classes to use and I'm not sure where to begin..

Comment: if u using custom class name means u need to write media-query for many resolutions.

Comment: Yeah.  That's gonna be the case for me as far as my project is concerned.